# What is an approximate ancillary statistic?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, definition, fisher-information, ancillary-statistics

In the article *Assessing the Accuracy of the Maximum Likelihood Estimator: Observed Versus Expected Fisher Information* the authors use the expression "approximate ancillary statistic". This expression is used in a lot of others articles.  Anyone know's the definition of approximate ancillary statistics?

Answer (score 2):

So, better late than never I guess. The textbook "Principles of Statistical Inference" explains this rather cleanly (excerpt [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fws1BjzOzAEC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=observed%20information%20approximate%20ancillary&source=bl&ots=5Rl94qeq_-&sig=_PQ5dY4u1WqC2K4Z8gr8iRABNYY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN_9rPjq7XAhWH5oMKHX4aBc44ChDoAQhcMAk#v=onepage&q=observed%20information%20approximate%20ancillary&f=false)):

> A statistic $a$ is *approximately ancillary* for the estimation of $\theta$ if the asymptotic distribution of $a$ is free of $\theta$

So, it allows you to condition on statistics that are weakly associated with $\theta$ as long as this dependence approaches zero in some suitable sense.

The observed Fisher information is one such "approximate ancillary" and using it as your variance term for a Wald-type confidence interval about the MLE will approximate a full conditional inference given *some* true ancillary (should it exist). The beauty of their result is that observed Fisher information is universally available for well-behaved (regular) parametric models and it provides some reassurance that the conditional (post-data) confidence will be approximately equal to the unconditional (pre-data) coverage.

Note however that the authors of the paper you read were not able to theoretically establish the approximate ancillarity of observed information for non-translation models, although they suspect it was the case based on simulations.

Comment: Also, some general discussion here: http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/sstest/oldpdf/A20n41.pdf